# Reduce for object in object in Array of Objects with FP

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I get the following data from an API:

```
[
    { names: { name: 'Pete', name;'Claus' } },
    { names: { name: 'Paul', name;'Claus' } },
    { ... }
]
```

How can I get an array containing only those objects that have the name *`Claus`* in them with `reduce`,`filter`, `map` and such methods?

This does it - but not in a functional style though:

```
var newMap = []
var map = this.array
for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
    if(map[i] && map[i].involvements[j])
      if(map[i].involvements[j].full_name === 'Claus') {
        newMap.push(map[i])
    }
  }
}
this.array = newMap
```

Some bits not very much though:

```
 search(){
    let map = this.submissions
    .map( (x,i) => x.involvements.filter(x => x.full_name === 'Claus'))
    .filter( x => x.length != 0 )
    console.log(map)
  }
```

Comment: That's an invalid json because has repeated keys.

Comment: Yeah, well thats what the API looks like.

Comment: Be sure about the JSON you're receiving because you won't be able to solve your problem with that invalid JSON.

Comment: Please share the correct array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Data Structure

Based on your code, you have the following data structure:

```
[
  {
    involvements: [
      { full_name: 'Claus' },
      { full_name: 'Peter Paker' }
    ]
  },
  // more involvements
]
```

## Code

What you want to do is to *filter* if *some* `involvement` contains an object with the property `full_name`. Coincidentally there are the functions [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
const search = (x, xss) =>
    xss.filter(xs => xs['involvements'].some(y => y['full_name'] === x))

search('Claus', data)
```

## Working Code Example

```js
const data = [{
    involvements: [{
        full_name: 'Claus'
      },
      {
        full_name: 'Peter Parker'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    involvements: [{
        full_name: 'Clark Kent'
      },
      {
        full_name: 'Kristin Wells'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const search = (x, xss) =>
  xss.filter(xs => xs['involvements'].some(y => y['full_name'] === x))

console.log(
  search('Claus', data)
)
```